# Auto update web.sitemap after adding aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, navigation, sitemap

I'm using site navigation in my site which uses `<asp:sitemap>` and
every time I add a new aspx file to my website I have to edit my web.sitemap manually. I'd like to know if there's any way to update web.sitemap automatically (that's not database driven).

I searched for a solution and found these links but to be honest I couldn't implement/use them. (I'm new to asp.net)

[stop editing 'web sitemap'](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17133/Stop-editing-web-sitemap-Let-unknown-pages-dynamic)

[Building a dynamic SiteMap in ASP.NET 2.0 for a large website](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16860/Building-a-dynamic-SiteMap-in-ASP-NET-2-0-for-a-la)

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to create your own custom site map provider, use File IO to read all of the files with an ASp.NET extension, cache it, and use this to build the sitemap from.

Comment: you mean something like this:
foreach(aspx in sitepath) {
   add <sitemap:node>
}
if yes, is it possible to read title and description of pages?

Comment: You could also look into software solutions like A1 Sitemap Generator or similar (Note: The crawler will follow links on the website already there... Meaning if a page is not linked, it may not be added to the web.sitemap file either)

Answer (score 0):

...or use a pre-build system. Here's a tutorial that utilises one: http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/ASP.NET/Dynamic-Sitemap-and-Navigation-in-ASPNet/

Comment: now I figured out how to make _ScionSiteMapProvider_ to work.
But now problem is title and description of pages. is it possible to set title and description of pages like `this.header.title;`?